# How to get crash reason, if it is crashing from URL opened in iframe in Webview in iOS?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

URL opened in cordova project in iframe, is causing crash on iOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Direct way of checking the webview crash, or atleast which i know.
I can recommend some steps for you towards this:

```
i) open your content/web page in browser and check for all errors it throws in browser
ii) stop/delete all unnecessary service calls
iii) webview sandbox environment has to be within 10 MB
iv) make sure you are not getting any 404 errors, use browser to check this easily
v) update and refine your codes to do be simple and avoid any service calls which is not required in webview environment
```

Comment: Also consider this as webview crash will eventually crash your app which has invoked it. too much data as well can crash the web view.